# Sending and Receiving App Data from Different Devices

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm trying to build a listing app in android, and I want different devices to share their data to each other if they wanted

example 1:
User A created 5 entries in the app.
User B wants to copy the entries created by User A

example 2:
User A deleted/ modified the list from his app
User B wants to copy the changes, but first, he wants to check the modifications/ deletions created by User A.

Assumption 1: Users just have a free data from their network provider. (they can't access all sites, besides m.facebook.com / free.facebook.com)

Assumption 2: User A and B's devices has bluetooth enabled

Assumption 3: ShareIt by lenovo also installed.

Assumption 4: The device may or may have sim card slot

Can you give me some tips here ? I want to utilize the use of shareit or bluetooth if ever. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using NFC(Near Field Communication) you can also Sending and Receiving App Data from Different Devices. but for that device is must be supported with the NFC.

please refer below link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Comment: how bout for devices that were not supported by NFC ?

Comment: For that you have to check NFC available in our device or not.

Like this:
 mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

Comment: I mean, I need something that will work both on with or without NFC